# Context Menu item must been clicked twice to disappear

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, event-handling, contextmenu

I'm creating a context menu on a listview to be able to execute functions on specific items. When Right Clicking, the context menu show properly, part of the function execute but not entirely, and the context menu get displayed again.

I tried to move context menu creation and binding in the load function of the form, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
private JsonReport _lastItemTag;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void ReportTemplateManager_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Initialize context menu for template control
    ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
    cm.MenuItems.Add("Load", new EventHandler(LoadReport_Click));
    template_listview.ContextMenu = cm;
}

private void Template_listview_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    bool match = false;
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in template_listview.Items)
        {
            if (item.Bounds.Contains(new Point(e.X, e.Y)))
            {
                template_listview.ContextMenu.Show(template_listview, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                match = true;
                _lastItemTag = item.Tag as JsonReport;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!match)
            _lastItemTag = null;
    }
}
```

The function below get executed, but is not closing the form, I have to click it again to close the context menu and the form itself...

```
private void LoadReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_lastItemTag != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loading"); // This get executed
        _lastItemTag = null;
        this.Close(); // This doesnt close the form on the first time
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the `LoadReport` function can be executed "partially" and not close the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are showing the menu twice.

By assigning your context menu to the `ContextMenu` property, the menu will open automatically when you right click the list view.  There is no need to manually show the menu.

In addition, there is no need to loop through the menu items to find the match.  I'm not even sure what you are trying to do by handling the `MouseClick` event of the list view.  I think you can eliminate that method altogether.

The `sender` argument of the menu item event handler contains the menu item that was clicked.  You can just cast it and grab the `Tag` property from there:

```
private JsonReport _lastItemTag;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void ReportTemplateManager_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Initialize context menu for template control
    ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();

    //The event handler will be called when this menu item is clicked.
    cm.MenuItems.Add("Load", new EventHandler(LoadReport_Click));

    template_listview.ContextMenu = cm;
}

private void LoadReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //The 'sender' argument is the menu item that was clicked
    //In this case, it is the Load menu item so cast the sender
    var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;

    //Now get the Tag property and cast it to JsonReport
    _lastItemTag = menuItem.Tag as JsonReport;

    if (_lastItemTag != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loading"); // This get executed
        this.Close(); // This doesnt close the form on the first time
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution could have worked but I'm interested in the listview item tag and not the menu item, so it's not working in my case...

Comment: I had to make a few adjustment by keeping the MouseClick event on the listview to be able to store the item, however thank you for your answer !

Comment: Ok, that explains it a bit more.  I still don't think you need to call `Show` on your context menu, though.

Comment: I removed it ! The MouseClick function only get the selected item and store it, then the LoadReport_Click does her stuff on her own ! I just didn’t know that binding a context menu to a control will automatically take care of all clicks event ! Thanks for your answer